# How to run some JS that is using ActiveX .. from Java

Tags: java, javascript, activex

I have to use a device in a java (1.5) swing program.
Problem is the vendor des not provide APIs for Java. 
They provide Visual C++ support, python, JS, VBSCript APIs

Unfortunately, the JDK's script engine and Rhino do not support activex even on windows platform.

When running this simple code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScriptEngine runtime = null;
    try {
        runtime = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
        Object o =  runtime.eval( new FileReader( "something.js" ) );
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I get an error like

```
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "ActiveXObject"
```

which I understand as 'no activex support' (correct me if I'm wrong)

Is there any activex compliant javascript interpreter I could use in java ?

One option I'm evaluating is to control an IE in Java with Jacob. Make that IE invisible and execute some JS scripts that make use of the activeX to display the result.
Then .... get the data somehow from the body of the page.

If someone has already done this, let me know if it worked :)
I'm puzzled on the futureproof-ness of this option

My env is windows7, IE8, java5, eclipse

Thank you

Comment: Futureproof?  I don't think so; unless you're paying Oracle for support Java 5 has been unsupported for 3 years already.

Comment: Hi Pointy, you are right for Java5. I was thinking of next IE versions,

Comment: Well I don't think IE8 can run on Windows 8 either; in fact I'm not even sure IE9 will run on Windows 8.